# customized image dimensions not showing in the featured image in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, image

I am trying to customize the image dimension in my child theme of my wordpress theme called Gameleon.Inside my functins.php I have added these lines.

```
    <?php

    add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' ); 

    add_image_size('small', 75, 75, true);
    add_image_size('medium', 280, 280, true);
    add_image_size('single-post-thumbnail', 660, 350, true);

   if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
   the_post_thumbnail('single-post-thumbnail');
   } 
   ?>
```

I want the functionality in my wordpress website that when I click on an image in the slider it gives me detail of my post with a featured image and some text underneath. I want the size of the image to be of size 660*350.But when I downloaded the image,the default size is from the parent theme which I dont want.What can I do?